# the Castelnuovo's theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I've studied Castelnuovo's theorem in Beauville's book.
The theorem says that if $S$ is a non ruled surface than $\chi_{top}(S) \ge0$. In particular if $S$ is a surface of general type $\chi_{top}(S)>0$.
Are there some applications of this nice theorem?

Answer (score 1):

One application is the classification of surfaces of general type. For this, you want to know invariants related to the surface.

Comment: can you tell me some references? I know that there is a lot of material on web but i prefer to have a book.

Comment: I've honestly just come across this when reading papers and wikipedia articles, so not off the top of my head. My best guess would be the book Barth / Peters "Compact Complex Surfaces"..

Comment: what you red on web is not related to this theorem but is about the castelnuovo's rationality theorem.

Comment: To be fair, you can find Beauville's book on the web.